# How do I create an Excel Macro using VBA to paste a specific formula?

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to set up a macro using VBA that will paste the following formula into whatever cell is currently active.

```
=CONCATENATE("For the Year Ended ",TEXT(CYEDATE(),"mmmm dd, yyyy")," ")
```

This formula will insert the current date and text into financial statements in a ProFX excel workpaper. Once i create the Macro, I'll ad a keyboard shortcut.  It's easily done with copy and paste, but I'd like to understand how to make it work.

Thanks!

Comment: `Selection.Formula = "=CONCATENATE(""For the Year Ended "",TEXT(CYEDATE(),""mmmm dd, yyyy""),"" "")"` should do the trick. If you get stuck, just record a macro of you pasting this formula in a cell and it will pretty much write it for you.

Comment: Don't know if it helps, but if you hit `CTRL+;` it will insert the date for you. (I know you also want text, but just thought to mention that)

Comment: That did it. I tried the recorder, but I've been trying to get better with VBA and wanted to see how it worked. Thanks for helping a newbie....

Comment: You could also give the cell a custom number format of `"For the Year Ended " mmmm dd, yyyy` and just add the date to the cell.  Upside is that you can then perform calculations on the date in the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try recording a macro if you're new to VBA. Then click on the Visual Basic editor to see how the code is written. Then you can replace the specific range you're pasting into to be the more generic reference to the Active cell.

One example of code you can use is this:
1. Store your formula as a String variable
2. Set the formula of the ActiveCell to be

```
Dim formula As String
formula = "=CONCATENATE(""For the Year Ended "",TEXT(CYEDATE(),""mmmm dd, yyyy""),"" "")"

ActiveCell.formula = formula
```